# Splitting only returns System.String[] instead of actual value

Tags: c#, split

I've searched a while now and still haven't found anything.

My Problem is, I want to simply split a value, delivered from a Textbox
as soon as a 1 appears.

```
string t1 = textBox1.Text;
string[] split = t1.Split(new Char[] {'1'});
```

I'm delivering the value written in my variable into another Textbox.
Now my problem is, it won't display the stuff that comes after the 1, as it should in the split method. Instead it displays System.String[]. Anybody have some help ?

Edit:

complete code part of my program:

```
 {
                string t1 = textBox1.Text;
                string[] split = t1.Split(new Char[] { });
                textBox1.Text = split.ToString(); 
                if (split.Length == 2)
                    textBox4.Text = split[1];          


                url = "https://www.google.de/search?q=" + textBox3.Text + "&um=1&client=" + split[1] + "-a&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&hl=de&" + textBox2.Text + "=lnms&sa=X&ei=Re2YUd-RCYiC4gThw4GwAQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAA&biw=1920&bih=951

                textBox4.Text = url;
            }
```

Comment: How do you want to convert the array to a string?

Comment: I don't know, could you tell me ? @ SLaks

Comment: You probably should try to read split[0] to see what's in array, or to use split.Length to find out how many strings are stored in array. Rgds,

Comment: I'm sorry, but i'm pretty new to c#, so is there any way I can split this variable without using an array ?

Comment: I don't get it. If TextBoxOne value is `Hello1Word`, TextBoxTwo should be `Word`?

Comment: Did you remember to enable AcceptReturn? I might have spelled this wrong... on my tablet atm.

Comment: @ Gabriel: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are probably assigning the result to the textbox like this:

```
textBox2.Text = split.ToString();
```

The `ToString()` will be converting the `string[] split` array to a string, which by default just returns the name of the type, in this case `System.String[]`.

In order for you to be able to use it, the `split` array should have at least two items in it; namely, all the substrings in the textbox that were separated by `/` characters.

I suspect you want to use all the characters after the `/` like so:

```
if (split.Length >= 2)
    textBox2.Text = split[1];
```

---

`String.Split()` will work like this:

If your input text was: `"ABCD/EFGH"`, then `split` would be:

```
split[0] == "ABCD";
split[1] == "EFGH";
```

And if your input text was: `"ABCDEFG"`, then `split` would be:

```
split[0] == "ABCDEFG"; // There is no split[1]
```

And if your input text was: `"AB/CD/EF"`, then `split` would be:

```
split[0] == "AB"
split[1] == "CD"
split[2] == "EF"
```

Note that these last two cases both have `split.Length != 2`.

What do you want to do for the last case, where there are two (or even more) `/` characters in the input?

---

[EDIT] Looking at your last update, this line of code is wrong:

```
textBox1.Text = split.ToString();
```

It should be:

```
if (split.Length > 0)
    textBox1.Text = split[0];
```

Read the first part of my answer above for an explanation about what `split.ToString()` does!

Also, this line is wrong:

```
string[] split = t1.Split(new Char[] { });
```

It should be

```
string[] split = t1.Split(new [] {'/'});
```

You didn't specify which character to split on. From your comments below this anwser, I assume you actually want to split on `'/'`.

Finally! Your line starting with:

```
url = "https: ...
```

uses `split[1]` so you need to protect it with an if:

```
if (split.Length > 1)
    url = "https: ...
else
    url = "<DIDN'T WORK!>"; // Or something! :)
```

Comment: yes, now if I enter something in textBox1, this will change to System.String[].

Comment: also, an error message appears, saying this index is out of the arrayrange

Comment: Can you try that code I suggested? The `if (split.Length >= 2) textBox2.Text = split[1];` part. (I'm guessing at what your second textbox is called; you will need to change my code to whatever it's really called).

Comment: Splitting the value of textBox1 by 1 was only for testing. Actually I want to split it at "/", because I'm trying to split a URL

Comment: Ok, so that shouldn't make any difference to the code I suggested.

Comment: Yes, i know ^^ just some additional Information... Yes I've tried your suggested code and as a result I get an IndexOutOfRange exception. I guess try catch won't make a change ?

Comment: Can you add the exact code you are using into your question? The code I posted cannot generate an IndexOutOfRange exception, because I am checking that the length of the `split` array is greater then or equal to 2 before attempting to access `split[1]`.

Comment: If you want, i can send you my entire code, I guess you'd have a better overview of the problem.

Comment: Urk, no we just need to see your code where you call `Split()` and use the result to fill the text box.

Comment: Okay, I've changed my original Post. You can now see the code. Thanks for the effort so far !

Comment: Your second to last line, the one with assigning url, gets split[1] without ever checking the length. That's your error. Also, you aren't giving split any characters, so it's not going to split at all.

Comment: okay, the second point was obvious, I had that in my code before, but it still didn't work. how will ich check the length? I thought line 5 would do the job.

Comment: @user2399053 As MikePrecup stated and as I put in my answer (near the end), the index out of bounds is coming from the line starting with `url = ...` because you are using `split[1]` without checking the length. I suspect `split[]` only had zero length because you forgot the `'/'` character in the call to `Split()`.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer and change all the places it talks about the `1` character to `/` because (a) now I know you really want to use `/` and (b) I think the `1` is being confused with the array index used for `split[1]`.